# Filering columns based on Row values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can filter rows based on a column value, using a boolean series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4), ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['W','X','Y','Z'])

>>> df[df['W'] < 0]
          W         X         Y         Z
A -1.080180 -0.512936  0.810030  0.135316
D -0.713363  0.376887 -0.334995  0.864555
```

How can I filter rows based on a boolean series, how can I filter column based on a column boolean series?  something like this.

```
df[df.loc['A'] > 1] ##It's wrong syntax I know.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close, need `loc` with `:` for select all rows by condition:

```
np.random.seed(45)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,4), ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['W','X','Y','Z'])
print (df)
          W         X         Y         Z
A  0.989012  0.549545  0.281447  0.077290
B  0.444469  0.472808  0.048522  0.163324
C  0.115951  0.627392  0.856182  0.650102
D  0.990722  0.470351  0.618294  0.282667
E  0.976003  0.673068  0.440531  0.289687

df1 = df.loc[:, df.loc['A'] > .5]
print (df1)
          W         X
A  0.989012  0.549545
B  0.444469  0.472808
C  0.115951  0.627392
D  0.990722  0.470351
E  0.976003  0.673068
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was tried somewhat similar not sure what I was missing.